# How to populate key value pair on materialize modal

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to populate the key and value on modal on click of button, which i am unable to populate.

I am trying to get modelinfo(JSON) except "modelname". I want all the keys and values to be populated on modal. But here i am able to get only last values.

Here is my code:

```
$('.addAttribute').click(function() {
  if (deviceIdStatus === 'old') {
    var getModelDetails = ajaxServices("/getServices/models", "GET");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(getModelDetails));
    $('#modelName').val(getModelDetails[0].modelinfo.modelname).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.each(getModelDetails, function(i, el) {
      $.each(el.modelinfo, function(key, val) {
        if (key != "modelname") {
          console.log(key + ":" + val);
          $(".addModel").trigger("click");
        };
        $.each(el.modelinfo, function(key, val) {
          if (key != "modelname") {
            console.log(key + ":" + val)
            $(".modelAttribute").val(key);
            $(".modelType").val(val);
          }
        });
      })
    })
  }
});
```

On click of addAttribute button, i am fetching the key value on modal. But i am getting only the last value everywhere. I am checking based on the deviceId. If the deviceId is old then the model has key and value in database. I am failing to fetch the values from database. I am using orientdb.

This is the JSON, where i am trying to populate modelinfo except modelname

```
[{
  "@type": "d",
  "@class": "models",
  "templateId": "#31:0",
  "modelinfo": {
    "modelname": "obdDataModel",
    "temp": "2",
    "hum": "1",
    "co": "0"
  },
  "deviceid": "ANX2345613",
  "@rid": "#39:0",
  "@version": 9
}]
```

Here is how my output looks like, output has only last key value populated:

[image: Output]

Comment: My JSON is below (Incase if you can't view an image)                                                                                            [  
   {  
      "@type":"d",
      "@class":"models",
      "templateId":"#31:0",
      "modelinfo":{  
         "modelname":"obdDataModel",
         "temp":"2",
         "hum":"1",
         "co":"0"
      },
      "deviceid":"ANX2345613",
      "@rid":"#39:0",
      "@version":9
   }
]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from here.

```html
$(".modelAttribute").val(key);
$(".modelType").val(val);
```

jQuery Class selector will change all elements' value.

Are you write exactly number of the content containers like this?

```html
<!-- div 1 -->
<div>
  <input type="text" class="modelAttribute" />
  <input type="text" class="modelType" />
</div>
<!-- div 2 -->
<div>
  <input type="text" class="modelAttribute" />
  <input type="text" class="modelType" />
</div>
<!-- div 3 -->
<!-- div 4 -->
```

You should code like this:

```html
  $.each(el.modelinfo, function(key, val) {
    if (key != "modelname") {
      // create element
      var template = `
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="modelAttribute" value="${key}" />
          <input type="text" class="modelType" value="${value}" />
        </div>
      `;
      $("#bigContainerWhatever").append(template);
    }
});
```